# How to make customize date and time picker in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How to make custom date and time picker in flutter like this or is there any plugin[image]

Comment: please give more explanation about question

Answer (score 1):

I once had the same issue. The default DatePicker and TimePicker have limited options for customization.

## Option A) Copy the Flutter-Code and customize it

You can copy the entire original flutter-code and customize it to your wishes. It's kinda much to follow through, but the flutter-code is very useful, especially if you want to be able to gain controls over FocusNodus e.g. with your keyboard or for accessibility. It also handles localizations and different week styles.

[calendar_date_picker.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/calendar_date_picker.dart)

**It's not the best solution but it's better then writing it all by yourself imho**

## Option B) Plugins

[syncfusion_flutter_datepicker](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker) (it's commercial though, but it's the most promising for customization)

## Option C) Create it yourself

Don't forget that a DatePicker is very complex. It should respect accessibility and localizations. This will probably take longer than option A. Dont' forget the weekstyles that the original flutter-code handles correctly:
[calendar_date_picker.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/calendar_date_picker.dart) (from flutter sdk, line 904++)

```dart
  ///     ┌ Sunday is the first day of week in the US (en_US)
  ///     |
  ///     S M T W T F S  ← the returned list contains these widgets
  ///     _ _ _ _ _ 1 2
  ///     3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  ///
  ///     ┌ But it's Monday in the UK (en_GB)
  ///     |
  ///     M T W T F S S  ← the returned list contains these widgets
  ///     _ _ _ _ 1 2 3
  ///     4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ///
```